NeoVim C++ set virtual function font
I'm using coc-clangd and nvim-treesitter in NeoVim, and I have the following requirements.

set the global variable identifiers to bold
set the virtual function identifiers to italic
set the macro identifiers to a specific color

It seems nvim-treesitter's classification of identifer was not detailed enough. And I want the rules should only be adopted in C++.

[vi.se] seems like a better place to ask this.
